# Dynamically add title to e_charts in R

Tags: r, dictionary, purrr, title, echarts4r

Hello I would like to be able to generate a list of e_charts in r using `map()` and `purrr` but I don't seem to be quite able to work out a way to dynamically add the title to each of the charts based on the character in the nested column. This is my code and a snapshot of the current output that it produces:

```
`make_a_plot <- function(df) {
df %\>% group_by(week) %\>%
summarise(Items =sum(Items)) %>% arrange(week) %>%
e_charts(week) %>%
e_line(serie = Items,legend = FALSE) %>%
e_x_axis(type='category')
                             }

df_new %>%
nest(data = -store) %>%
mutate(my_plot = map(data, make_a_plot))
pull(my_plot)`
```

[image]

Does anyone know if it's even possible to add the title in such a way? And if yes - how would I need to go about setting up the code?

Comment: It is possible, but right now it's difficult to tell what it is you're doing because your question isn't reproducible. It's been a while since you asked, but if you're still looking for that answer, edit your question, making it reproducible. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).